# Slice bounds out of range when its obviously not

Tags: go

I have the following test code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    t1 := map[string]string{
        "1": "abcdefghijk",
        "2": "abcdefghijk",
        "3": "abcdefghijk",
        "4": "abcdefghijk",
        "5": "abcdefghijk"}
    o := 5
    a, b := t1["3"]
    fmt.Print("Selected line is: ")
    fmt.Println(a)
    if b {
        fmt.Print("Output is ")
        fmt.Println(a[o-1 : 1])
    }
}
```

But I get this error when I run it:

```
$ go run test.go
Selected line is: abcdefghijk
Output is panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [4:1]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/jd/_Go/test1/test.go:18 +0x3e1
exit status 2
```

The slice is 11 characters long, so how can [4:1] be out of range?!?
Obviously I'm doing something super stupid, but at the pull-hair-out stage, and willing to go though world wide embarrassment to get it figured it out.

Thanks!
JD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second number in a slice expression is the index, not the number of characters. You are accessing `a[4:1]`, from `a[4]` to `a[1]`

Instead: `fmt.Println(a[o-1 : o])`

Comment: See!  I knew it was something dum :)   Thank you